# Numbered lists using python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

Is there any way to create list in python like that:

> 1. Text1
>    1.1   Text2
>    1.2   Text3
> 2. Text4
>    2.1   Text5
>    2.1.1 Text6
>    2.1.2 Text7

I tried creating paragraphs with 'List Number' and 'List number 2' styles, but I can't modify the numbers.
So I just concatenated numbers with strings, but Word doesn't see it as a bullet list.⁷

Comment: Please add the code you wrote so far.

Comment: @Ada. In this one case I'd say the prose description is adequate. It's a non-trivial problem, but OP has accurately described the initial attempts at a solution that I first tried before jumping down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a function wrapping some functionality in python-docx to do exactly what you want: [`haggis.files.docx.list_number`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.files.docx.list_number).

Let's say you made some paragraphs in document `doc` corresponding to the items you want to number:

```
doc = ...
p1 = doc.add_paragraph('Text1', style='List Number')
p1 = doc.add_paragraph('Text2', style='List Number')
p3 = doc.add_paragraph('Text3', style='List Number')
p4 = doc.add_paragraph('Text4', style='List Number')
p5 = doc.add_paragraph('Text5', style='List Number')
p6 = doc.add_paragraph('Text6', style='List Number')
p7 = doc.add_paragraph('Text7', style='List Number')
```

Now you can set the attributes of the paragraphs to make the list:

```
list_number(doc, p1, prev=None, level=0)
list_number(doc, p2, prev=p1, level=1)
list_number(doc, p3, prev=p2, level=1)
list_number(doc, p4, prev=p3, level=0)
list_number(doc, p5, prev=p4, level=1)
list_number(doc, p6, prev=p5, level=2)
list_number(doc, p7, prev=p6, level=2)
```

To achieve the specific formatting that you want, you could create a list style in your document template that fits your needs. Assign that style to the paragraphs before you set the numbering scheme. The default `List Number` style will likely be sufficient for simple cases.

If you had a list of texts and levels for your list, you could use a loop to generate the list:

```
texts = [f'Text{n}' for n in range(1, 8)]
levels = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2]
prev = None
for text, level in zip(texts, levels):
    p = doc.add_paragraph(text, style='List Number')
    list_number(doc, p, prev=prev, level=level)
    prev = p
```